Spark - NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater

I am designing a pipeline to get data from finnhub into Kafka Topic.

Then I use Spark_streaming to bring data from Kafka Topic into Cassandra

Finally, the raw data from Cassandra is processed through Spark_Streaming into MySQL and visualized using Superset.


***Note: I did this process in Ubutu
After I run Spark the error is as follows:
24/10/07 23:28:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

2024-10-07 23:28:36,643 - INFO - Data Processing Application Started ...

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.2

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SparkContext: OS info Linux, 6.8.0-45-generic, amd64

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SparkContext: Java version 1.8.0_422

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka, Cassandra, and MySQL

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -\> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -\> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -\> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -\> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: tuanle

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: tuanle

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:

24/10/07 23:28:37 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: tuanle; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: tuanle; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY

24/10/07 23:28:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45507.

24/10/07 23:28:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker

24/10/07 23:28:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster

24/10/07 23:28:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information

2024-10-07 23:10:26,788 - INFO - Printing Schema of finnhub_df:

root
|-- key: binary (nullable = true)
|-- value: binary (nullable = true)
|-- topic: string (nullable = true)
|-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
|-- offset: long (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

2024-10-07 23:28:52,555 - INFO - Callback Server Starting

2024-10-07 23:28:52,556 - INFO - Socket listening on ('127.0.0.1', 35229)

24/10/07 23:10:29 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query \[id = a36d5715-9173-470d-8a1a-81024ad89d0f, runId = 3b2625ff-455b-411a-8f55-e3d50acb524d\] terminated with error

Exception in thread "stream execution thread for \[id = a36d5715-9173-470d-8a1a-81024ad89d0f, runId = 3b2625ff-455b-411a-8f55-e3d50acb524d\]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)

2024-10-07 23:15:29,052 - INFO - Starting to process data from Cassandra and save to MySQL

2024-10-07 23:15:29,549 - ERROR - An error occurred: An error occurred while calling o101.load.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less

2024-10-07 23:15:30,312 - INFO - Application stopped

2024-10-07 23:15:30,312 - INFO - Closing down clientserver connection

I use the following command to run Spark:
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.2,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1 --jars /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar processing_data.py
Which versions I use: Spark-3.5.2, Scala-2.12.18, Kafka-2.13-3.8.0, mysql-connector-j-9.0.0, cassandra-4.1.7...

That's not the error - This is - NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater as well as ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less. Note - if you have Scala 2.12 installed, then Kafka should also be installed for the same version
